# jQueryUI Progressbar won't ease

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, easing

When I apply the following code it sets the correct bar value but doesnt do any easing?

```
$("#myBar").progressbar({ value: 25, speed: 1500, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});
```

What am I missing, any help appreciated!

Thanks

---

Solution:

I kinda worked it out myself

```
$("#myBar").progressbar({ value: 25, speed: 1500, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});
```

was indeed invalid code (thanks Orenet!), using:

```
$('#myBar div').stop().animate({width: val + '%'},1000, 'easeOutBounce');
```

didn't work immediately as the div with the actual bar was hidden even initializing it before didnt work. At the moment i am just unhide it. any better solution?

Comment: the has be previously initialized with  
    $( "#myBar" ).progressbar({value: 0});

Comment: I added my own solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I kinda worked it out myself

```
$("#myBar").progressbar({ value: 25, speed: 1500, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});
```

was indeed invalid code (thanks Orenet!), using:

```
$('#myBar div').stop().animate({width: val + '%'},1000, 'easeOutBounce');
```

didn't work immediately as the div with the actual bar was hidden even initializing it before didnt work. At the moment i am just unhide it. any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use `speed` or `easing` with the default `progressbar` of jquery.

please read the [progressbar documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar).

Comment: http://ask.altervista.org/demo/how-do-you-animate-the-value-for-a-jquery-ui-progressbar/demo2.html - he used: .animate({width: wD + '%'},1000, 'easeOutBounce'); doesnt work for me either

Comment: another source for me was this: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3469 dunno if this is still up2date

Comment: then you should use `animate` as in the examples you gave. the code in the question is invalid...